# how change nginx temp & log folder or disable logging completely

Tags: windows, logging, nginx, read-only

I'm running nginx 1.3.5 under windows seven, I need to execute nginx directly from a read-only media (CD or DVD), but when I want to run it, it fails with this error:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "logs/error.log" fail
ed (5: Access is denied)
2012/08/28 13:52:46 [emerg] 5604#2864: CreateDirectory() "J:\nginx-1.3.5/temp/client_body_temp" failed (5: Access is denied)
```

where J is my CD-ROM drive letter.
I've changed nginx.conf to disable logging completely, but seems anyway it still tries to build a file named 'error.log' in '/logs' folder & some extra temporary contents in '/temp' folder at the startup, so I want to change 'logs' & 'temp' directory path to windows temp folder (%temp%), but I dont have any idea that how can I do it.
Also I want to know why nginx still creates 'logs/error.log' after disableing error logging ?

Answer (score 1):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html lists the directives for controlling logging, specifcally you have the 2 following:

```
syntax:     access_log path [format [buffer=size]]; 
            access_log off;
default:    access_log logs/access.log combined;
context:    http, server, location, if in location, limit_except
```

and

```
syntax:     error_log file | stderr [debug | info | notice | warn | error | crit | alert | emerg];
default:    error_log logs/error.log error;
context:    main, http, server, location
```

so while you can completely disable the access_log, the same doesn't seem to be true for the error_log. Nevertheless you can still achieve the effect you want by adding the following to your nginx config;

```
error_log /dev/null emerg; #redirect the logging we can't shut off to a black hole;
acces_log off; #disable acces log
```

UPDATE:
just noticed the windows tag, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313111/1218566) for the windows /dev/null equivalent

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you can disable access logs but not errors ones.
Nginx is trying to create/write messages into log file which is located on the CD/DVD.
Try to set log directory into the HD partition, say C: or D: